# Why does a cheerio element log differently in a template literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I wonder why the first  part of code returns a string with the html form of the element while the second part of code returns an object

```
//1st part
const $ = cheerio.load(content);
console.log(`button |||||| ::::::: ${$('button[class="sc-ifAKCX kUaUob"]')}`); //logs '<button> ... </button>'

//2nd part
const btn= $('button[class="sc-ifAKCX kUaUob"]');
console.log(typeof(btn));
```

Comment: Are you asking why the template literal operator `$` is not overridden by the local `$` declaration?

Comment: The first part is actually inside a string literal and so, the object is converted to String whereas, in the second case, there is no such conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal JS behavior that's basically unrelated to Cheerio. When you pass an object to a template literal or concatenate it with a string, `.toString()` is invoked:

```js
const o = {toString: () => "hello world"};
console.log(`>> ${o} <<`); // => >> hello world <<
console.log(">> " + o + " <<"); // => >> hello world <<
```

It so happens that a Cheerio object's `.toString()` returns its HTML.